# META tags module description [node:summary] doesn't work

Tags: 8, meta-tags

I have a content type with title, image, body field (long text with summary). I use meta tag module and when I add in Description: [node:summary] or [node:field_body:summary] nothing appears in the meta description in view-source.

```
<meta name="title" content="..."
<meta name="image" content="..."
```

Title and image work, but not summary.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm, that the token `[node:summary]` works in metatag. But only for the original "body" field with exactly that name. Did you change the field name? Because the original "body" field is not "field_body".

Comment: Yes, i use custom field for body !

Comment: Then the solution is to use a body field with the machine name "body".